# Dimension of a measure space?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

Let's consider $\Omega = [0,1]^2$ and functions $f, g \colon \Omega \to [0,1]$ defined via $f(x, y) = x$ and $g(x,y) = y.$ Clearly, $f$ and $g$ are independent random variables that have uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. <s>However, as per the answer in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460485/existence-of-independent-uniform-random-variables), there is no such pair of functions if $\Omega = [0,1]$. (In fact, in the comments, it is claimed that the fact that the other function is supposed to be independent of the other already implies that the other function has to be constant almost everywhere).</s>

Now, I think this could generalize to the statement that if $\Omega = [0,1]^k$, then there could be upmost $k$ independent random variables with uniform distribution on $[0,1]$. Is this claim true, and, if it is, would this allow one to define a notion of ''dimensionality'' of a measure space $\Omega$ by asking how many random variables from $\Omega$ there can be that are independent of each other?  (Possibly having some other distribution than the uniform one)

As pointed out in the comments, I wrongly understood the conclusion from [the other post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1460485/existence-of-independent-uniform-random-variables) and there can be independent random variables $f,g  : [0,1] \to [0,1]$ that have uniform distribution. Just not if $f(x) = x$.

Comment: You misread the other answer.  There do, indeed, exist such $f,g$ on $[0,1]$.  In that other problem, we would conlude that no such $g$ exists in case $f$ is the identity on $[0,1]$.  In fact, $[0,1]$ with Lebesgue measure, and $[0,1]^2$ with $2$-dimensional Lebesgue measure are **isomorphic** measure spaces.

Comment: In fact, basically all atomless probability measure spaces in practice are isomorphic to $[0, 1]$ with Lebesgue measure. This includes, for example, $[0, 1]^n$ for any $n \in \mathbb{N}$, $[0, 1]^\mathbb{N}$, $\{0, 1\}^\mathbb{N}$, $\mathbb{R}^n$ with any probability measure absolutely continuous w.r.t. the $n$-dimensional Lebesgue measure, the Wiener measure space, and so on. So there’s no hope of any kind of notion of dimension of a probability measure space.

Comment: @GEdgar Now it makes me curious why there might be $g$ that is independent of $f$ but not if $f$ is the identity on $[0,1]$. (It makes the identity somewhat strangely special). Is there an intuitive way to understand why there are functions that restrict the number of available functions that are iid to the given one?

Comment: The problem with the identity is in some sense that it depends on "too much" information from its input. If you know anything at all about $x$, then you also know something about $f(x)$, and vice versa. Many other functions have this same problem - really it's quite special for functions to be totally independent of each other. Typical examples of independent functions are things like "the number obtained from $x$ by taking the odd/even index digits in its binary expansion". Informally, this only uses "half" of the information from the input.

Comment: Independence of random variables $f,g$ means independence of sigma-algebras $\sigma(f), \sigma(g)$.  But in case $f$ is the identity, then $\sigma(f)$ is the sigma-algebra of all Borel sets, so no sub-sigma-algebra of the Borel sets (except the trivial ones) can be independent of $\sigma(f)$.